# Adding php code in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have php code which I want to execute on button click event in function. I tried in various way with no luck. It's easy but I am new to this so could not do.

```
<?php
session_start();
$appId = '----'; 
$appSecret = '----'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'dev01.dev/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/';  //path to script folder
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" ><head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>JS/Ajax Facebook Connect</title>
 <script>

 function AjaxResponse()
 {

    alert("hi");
   }

function LodingAnimate() //Show loading Image
{
    $("#LoginButton").hide(); 
      AjaxResponse();    
}
 </script></head><body>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
?>
    <div id="results">    </div>
    <div class="results1">    </div>
    <div id="LoginButton">
    <button type="button" onclick="CallAfterLogin()" ?>Click Me!</button> 
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//-------
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    channelUrl: '<?php echo $return_url; ?>channel.php',
    oauth: true});};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());

function CallAfterLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response) {  //---
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate();                    
         } //if
             }); //---
          } 
       <div id="results"> 
          </div>
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If possible then I want to execute in ajaxResponse function. 
My code is:

```
if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException')) {
    require_once('facebook.php' );
    }
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appId,
        'secret' => $appSecret,
    ));
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($fbuser) 
    {
            try {
             $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/movies');echo '<pre>';
            foreach ($user_interest['data'] as $var)
        {
             $ID=$var['id'];
             $Name=$var['name'];
             echo '<br/>';
             print_r($Name); echo '<br/>';
             print_r($ID);
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: _It's easy but I am new to this so could not do._ contradicts to the fact you post a question but fail to supply why it is failing, but seems to be _easy_ to solve.

Comment: Have you done a 'view source' to see what the generated code looks like to the browser? That should give you good clues about what the problem might be. But in general, you best practice is to have as little dynamic JS code as possible. The better way of doing it is to generate a JSON array using php's `json_encode()`. Then the rest of your JS code should reference the values from there, rather than having dynamic PHP embedded in them.

Comment: seriously? this is the third stackoverflow thread you open for the same code. i already told you to get rid of the php stuff, you can do all that with the javascript sdk of facebook. and you reeeeally need to learn programming BEFORE starting with the facebook api, no offense...

Comment: You are right, it is easy. You click a button which sends a request to the server to run the php code and give you the results back. So which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: @luschn: I agree :P but each thread I start give me something different to learn, I am learning programming. I will take care

Comment: @Anigel: Yes it working quite well, but as it sending request to another page and retrieving result back which takes time. So I want second code which prints each movie and it's id to be called on button click in first page itself. I could do it but still I am in search of some better solution! luschn has already helped me a lot!

Comment: but you post almost the same code. and stackoverflow is not a platform to learn a programming language, it´s for specific problems. you created 3 threads for one little code part...

Comment: for learning to program, you may go to codeacademy.com or plenty of other pages, specialized for that

Comment: @luschn: I will check it. Three threads have same code but purpose was little different. One was to get movies, first one you solved was to remove addtional reload prob and this one was to make it more light! I apologize as I should dig it more and then I should post!